# how to traget a specific value on react in an onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created an option
with multiple values,
and I would like to recover this specific value when I click on this composting material but for the moment it only puts undefined
I would like to recover the "value"

however when I make a console.log outside of the onclick method I see the value displayed

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
      
chooseDay = (e) => {
  console.log('this value is',e.target.value)
}

  <li type='button' onClick={this.chooseDay} className='days'
            value = "2020-24-04" >
             Mon
            <small>24/04</small>
        </li>
```

expected result :  this value is : '2020-24.04';

but currently: undefined

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `e.target.value` you can try `e.currentTarget.value`, as [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `e.target`, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.

```
chooseDay = (e) => {
    console.log('this value is', e.currentTarget.value)
}
```